# Instance creation error when using factory_boy with mongoengine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, mongoengine, factory-boy

I'm trying to use factory_boy for testing my mongoengine database operations. Here's the mongoengine documents:

```
import mongoengine

class Address(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    street = mongoengine.StringField()

class Person(mongoengine.Document):
    name = mongoengine.StringField()
    address = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(Address)
```

Then I define the factory classes:

```
class AddressFactory(factory.mongoengine.MongoEngineFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Address

    street = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'street%d' % n)

class PersonFactory(factory.mongoengine.MongoEngineFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'name%d' % n)
    address = factory.SubFactory(AddressFactory)
```

And after I try to use them in test...

```
import unittest

class TestPerson(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_person_creation(self):
        person = PersonFactory.create()
        assert models.Plan.objects.get(address=plan.address).first()
```

...and get the following exception which to me looks like if I have not defined the class of the document in meta.model part of my factory class but I did. I guess I'm using the create() method in a wrong way I'm just not sure how.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/drill_ws/src/drill-hal/tests/test_store.py", line 76, in <module>
    person = PersonFactory.create()
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 564, in create
    return cls._generate(enums.CREATE_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 501, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 272, in build
    step.resolve(pre)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 221, in resolve
    self.attributes[field_name] = getattr(self.stub, field_name)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 375, in __getattr__
    extra=context,
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/declarations.py", line 321, in evaluate
    return self.generate(step, defaults)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/declarations.py", line 411, in generate
    return step.recurse(subfactory, params, force_sequence=force_sequence)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 233, in recurse
    return builder.build(parent_step=self, force_sequence=force_sequence)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 272, in build
    step.resolve(pre)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 221, in resolve
    self.attributes[field_name] = getattr(self.stub, field_name)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 375, in __getattr__
    extra=context,
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/declarations.py", line 321, in evaluate
    return self.generate(step, defaults)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/declarations.py", line 411, in generate
    return step.recurse(subfactory, params, force_sequence=force_sequence)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 233, in recurse
    return builder.build(parent_step=self, force_sequence=force_sequence)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 279, in build
    kwargs=kwargs,
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 315, in instantiate
    return self.factory._create(model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anton/.local/share/virtualenvs/drill-hal-TAWOMXlQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/mongoengine.py", line 26, in _create
    instance = model_class(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your error mentions `PlanFactory`, are you sure about the code you pasted? Can you take a look at `PersonFactory._meta.get_model_class()`?

Comment: @Xelnor My bad, I updated the exception message. ```PersonFactory._meta.get_model_class()``` returns ```<class 'Person'>```

Comment: Taking a look at the stack trace, I see two calls to `step.recurse(subfactory)`; are you sure the code you're posting matches exactly the one where you have the issue? If that's the case, I think the best would be to open an issue on the project itself — it looks like a bug!

Comment: OK, I have no idea then: your code seems to match exactly the one in the repository (https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/tests/test_mongoengine.py), yet the stack you show **doesn't** match — still too many calls to `step.recurse()`. Check the result of `FooFactory._meta.get_model_class()` for each of your factories, or open an issue with the actual code/error on the project tracker at https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues ;)